# XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent.total totalSize giving wrong value

Tags: ajax, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, ajax-upload

I am listening on `xhr.onprogress`

```
request.onprogress = function(e){
    return conf.progress ? conf.progress(e) : null;
};
```

where `conf.progress` is

```
function(e){
    var position = e.position || e.loaded;
    var total = e.totalSize || e.total;
    var percent = ((e.loaded/e.total)*100)+"";
    console.log(percent);
    console.log(position, total);
    console.log(e);
}
```

`percent` yields wrong value in console like `2.789069431137492e-11` and this is what `console.log(e)` prints

```
XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent
    bubbles: false
    cancelBubble: false
    cancelable: true
    clipboardData: undefined
    currentTarget: undefined
    defaultPrevented: false
    eventPhase: 2
    lengthComputable: false
    loaded: 4982035
    position: 4982035
    returnValue: true
    srcElement: undefined
    target: undefined
    timeStamp: 1323097256269
    total: 18446744073709552000
    totalSize: 18446744073709552000
    type: "progress"
    __proto__: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent
```

Why the `e.totalSize: 18446744073709552000` is so big and even after the document is completely loaded `e.loaded: 4982035` as `totalSize` should be equal to `loaded` when its complete

Comment: I noticed that `lengthComputable` is `false` in your case which, as I understand it, means you can't rely on `total`.

I can't find a reference online for the behavior of `total` when `lengthComputable` is false -- I thought that it would be 0.

David Flanagan's "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide" p508 is the only discussion I can find - all other search results for `lengthComputable` show people using it, but not discussing the behavior.

Comment: Book link: http://books.google.com/books?id=6TAODdEIxrgC&pg=PA508&lpg=PA508&dq=xhr2+lengthcomputable&source=bl&ots=ob9lDTNvXJ&sig=ir83LPAKveZzXDJOJe7-WBE0k1s&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mN36TuGDL8vMrQfPs8nqDw&ved=0CE8Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=xhr2%20lengthcomputable&f=false

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you're on a WebKit-based browser, it could very likely be a WebKit bug where a length of -1 is being casted without checking for a negative: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36156

Answer (score 0):

That's because [totalSize is set to the maximum value of an unsigned 64-bit integer when it is unknown](https://hg.mozilla.org/integration/mozilla-inbound/rev/7cde774aa665#l5.31). You gotta rely on `lengthComputable` to check whether a `content-length` header was returned or not.